# Obtaining location of location A and calculating its distance to location B

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am constructing an accommodation website which requires me to calculate the distance between two points:

- **Location A**: Is the accommodation building (if a user searches for a room, a room is assigned to a building, which has a generic postcode). As mentioned, each accommodation building has its postcode. Properties are assigned to an accommodation building which is how its location is determined. For example, property 1 is in accommodation building 3, which has a post code of `LS18 4AA`.
- **Location B**: Which is the University. The University has a generic latitude and longitude value.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

What I want to do, is that when a user views a property, it will get the postcode of the building it is in (accommodation building location is stored as postcode in db) and then calculate its distance away from the university location (which has one fixed lat/long value).

The only value that changes is the post code value based on what property a user is viewing.

**What I am struggling with**:

I just cannot get my head around how to get the postcode based on what property is the user is viewing, and then calculating its distance to to university. I.e. Location A is 7 miles away from Location B.

At the moment, I have figured out how to calculate distance between two lat long values, but since location A is a post code, I am unsure on how to convert those values.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
var x = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(52.482799000000000, -2.000643000000000, 52.48463500000000, -1.980759000000000);

function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2){
//  console.log(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2); 

// uni's location:
// var distanceFromSpecificPoint = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm.bind(null, 52.486637, -1.890952); 

  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km 
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1); // deg2rad below 
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
  var a =
    Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
    Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km 
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI / 180)
}

document.getElementById('result').textContent = x;

//console.log(x)
</script>
```

This line here:

```
var x = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(52.482799000000000, -2.000643000000000, 52.48463500000000, -1.980759000000000);
```

The final two values are the lat and long for the university's location. The first two values are just values entered for testing, and it works, the code calculates the distance between those two sets of data. But ideally, I would want the first two values to be replaced by long lat values based on the property the user is viewing, and the buildings postcode the property is in.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Googles Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?csw=1)

an example of the call needed can be seen below:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=POSTCODE&sensor=false
```

This will return a json response, however you can just parse through this as you need to